# LULC-2021: Layer error: User memory limit exceeded

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, sentinel-2, land-cover

I am trying to create a LULC map for Maharashtra State in India. I collected training polygons for 7 classes: Agriculture, Water, Builtup, Fallow Land, Barren Land, Wetlands, Other Vegetation. I am trying to classify them using Random Forest Algorithm.

```
var gcps = builtup.merge(water).merge(agriculture).merge(fallowland).merge(barrenland).merge(otherVegetation).merge(wetlands)

//The name of the property on the points storing the class lebel
var classProperty = 'landcover';

//Sample the input imagery to get a FeatureCollection of training data
var training = filtered.select(bands).sampleRegions({
  collection: gcps,
  properties: [classProperty],
  scale: 10
});

//Train the classifier
var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(50).train({
  features: training,
  classProperty: classProperty,
});

//Classify the input imagery
var classified = filtered.classify(classifier);

//Define color palette
var palette = [
  '57DA25', // agriculture (0) 
  '25DAD6', //waterbody (1) 
  'DAB625', //builtup (2) 
  '98ff00', // fallow land (3)
  '808b04',// barren land (4)
  'b6fdff', // wetlands (5)
  'ff6218' //other Vegetation (6)
];

Map.addLayer(classified.clip(combined_feature), {min:0, max: 6, palette: palette}, 'LULC-2021');
```

Here is my [complete code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/e7b277238906013d04c0f470b8473dff)

I understand that there are many points that have been collected, due to which the 'User Memory Limit' Error Occurs. So, either I will have to reduce the training points, or reduce the size of my study area.

But, is there any alternate way to execute the classification of a large study area, keeping the training points same? Please suggest how I can improve my code to achieve LULC, using GEE JavaScript Web API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You run out of memory because your training data set has `2,656,173` features. `sampleRegions()` where each region is a polygon will sample all points within those polygons, at the scale you specified (10m).

To control the number of pixels sampled, you can use `ee.Image.sample()` instead. Here below, I've sampled `200` pixels from each of your seven feature collections. I pick up the class value from the first feature in each collection, assuming all features represent within a collection only represents a single class (I didn't bother to validate that assumption).

```
var classProperty = 'landcover'
var samplesPerClass = 200
var filtered = filtered.median()

var training = ee.FeatureCollection(
  [
    builtup, 
    water, 
    agriculture, 
    fallowland, 
    barrenland, 
    otherVegetation, 
    wetlands
  ].map(function (featureCollection) {
    return filtered.select(bands)
      .sample({
        region: featureCollection.geometry(), 
        scale: 10, 
        numPixels: samplesPerClass
      })
      .map(function (point) {
        return point.copyProperties(featureCollection.first(), [classProperty])
      })
  })
).flatten()

var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(50).train({
  features: training,
  classProperty: classProperty,
  inputProperties: bands
})
var classified = filtered.classify(classifier)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/16614ad867a90219f2633953a0a6faab