# 'Supervised Classification'- 2016: Layer error: Computed value is too large

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm trying to classify my area of interest based on single signature shapefile having six classes Agriculture, Hills,Buildup, Fallow, Active_Surface_Miningand water_bodies.
Any suggestion or solution to tackle the error?

"signature file" access https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/?asset=users/vikknikkgujjar/kaliyana_signature_file

```js
//raster data from sentinel-2
s2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")
    
//geometry2 (AOI)

coordinates

    0: [75.11923156961176,27.56821903982507]
    1: [78.04159485086176,27.56821903982507]
    2: [78.04159485086176,29.51758053304302]
    3: [75.11923156961176,29.51758053304302]
    4: [75.11923156961176,27.56821903982507]


    var filtered = s2.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 30))
      .filter(ee.Filter.date('2015-01-01', '2016-12-31'))
      .select(['B8', 'B4', 'B3', 'B2'])
      .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(geometry2))
    
    var image = filtered.median();
    var rgbVis = {min: 0.0, max: 3000, bands: ['B8','B4', 'B3']};
    Map.addLayer(image ,rgbVis, 'Image');
    
    function maskS2clouds(image) {
      var qa = image.select('QA60');
    
      // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
      var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
      var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;
    
      // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
      var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
          .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
    
      return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
    }
    // FeatureCollection of land use land cover signature.
    var fc = ee.FeatureCollection('users/vikknikkgujjar/kaliyana_signature_file')
               
    
    // Select a single property.
    var Agriculture = fc.select('Agriculture');
    var Hills = fc.select('Hills');
    var Buildup = fc.select('Buildup');
    var Fallow = fc.select('Fallow');
    var Active_Surface_Mining = fc.select('Active_Surface_Mining');
    var water_bodies = fc.select('water_bodies');
    //merger training data
    
    var gcps = Agriculture.merge(Hills).merge(Buildup).merge(Fallow).merge(Active_Surface_Mining).merge(water_bodies);
    
    // Overlay the point on the image to get training data.
    var training = image.sampleRegions({
      collection: gcps, 
      properties: ['landcover'], 
      scale: 10
    });
    
    // Train a classifier.
    var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(50).train({
      features: training,  
      classProperty: 'landcover', 
      inputProperties: image.bandNames()
    });
    
    // // Classify the image.
    var classified = image.classify(classifier)
    var clip =  classified.clip(geometry2);
    Map.addLayer(clip, {min: 0, max: 6, palette: ['gray', 'brown', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']}, '2016');
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

You're having the same issue as the user I answered [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/427873/154371). Your training data set is huge, as you're sampling every pixel within the polygons in your feature collection. You can limit the amount of training data by sampling a subset of these polygons:

```
var classProperty = 'Classvalue'
var samplesPerClass = 100
var fc = ee.FeatureCollection('users/vikknikkgujjar/kaliyana_signature_file')
  .remap(
    [1, 2, 51, 102, 161, 186, 229], // Tweak this order to adjust your class values
    ee.List.sequence(0, 6), 
    classProperty
  )
var training = fc
  .map(function (feature) {
    return image
      .sample({
        region: feature.geometry(), 
        scale: 10, 
        numPixels: samplesPerClass
      })
      .map(function (point) {
        return point.copyProperties(feature, [classProperty])
      })
  })
  .flatten()
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/94ea23b206f738c1e039ce5cfcd26240